# Can I do anything about my exploding head?

Tags: sleep

I have Exploding Head Syndrome:

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploding_head_syndrome)

> Exploding head syndrome is a form of auditory hallucination and is a rare and relatively undocumented event in which a person experiences a loud bang in their head - any form of loud, indecipherable noise that seems to originate from inside the head.

Is there any effective way to make it stop? It doesn't happen very regularly, but when it does it's very annoying.

Comment: How long do your cases last? And how much sleep do you get?

Comment: @Nate could you roll that back? I personally much prefer having the name of the site there, which is why I used that style. We're not wikipedia, we don't need to use the citation style.

Comment: @Tim rolled back. I think the present form looks awkward, though. I'd rather have the reference source inline somehow. Probably a topic for meta discussion.

Comment: Probably, thanks for doing that. I'm not sure which is best now, but I don't like having to follow the link to find out what it is... Do you want to start the discussion?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for treatment suggestions which (currently) is off topic.